# Problem of regex to separate country names with numbers that follow them

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

I have to clean a column "Country" of a DataFrame where, sometimes, the country names are followed by numbers (for example we will see "France6" instead of France). I would like to separate the country name from the number that follows it.

I coded this function to solve the problem:

```
def new_name2(row):
    for item in re.finditer("([a-zA-Z]*)(\d*)",row.Country):
        row.Country=item.group(1)
    return row
```

We can see that I created two groups, the first one to catch the country name, and the other to separate the number. Following that, I should get (France)(6).

Unfortunately, when I run it, my Country column turns empty. This means that the first group that I get is not "France" but "" and I don't understand why, because on a regex website, I can see that my expression `([a-zA-Z]*)(\d*)` is working.

Comment: You don't need a function with pandas. What is your goal? To split the two parts? Delete the number? Please provide a reproducible input/output example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop rewrites `row.Country` each time *even with a zero-length match*!

Instead, you could [strip off the numbers directly](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)

```py
df["Country"] = df["Country"].str.rstrip("0123456789")
```

Using a dedicated Pandas method will almost-certainly be much faster than simple Python loop due to [vectorizing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods)

Answer (score -1):

Add a beginning and ending match like this:

```
^([a-zA-Z]*)(\d*)$
```

This will force it to match the entire string. Perhaps that was the problem.

If that doesn't work, try logging the regex result. Maybe your inputs are faulty.